# How to copy text from one XML file to another

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two large XML files, where some text in the first one is wrong and needs to be replaced with text from another xml file.

```
xml 1 

<phrase name="1111"><![CDATA[aaaa]]></phrase>
<phrase name="2222"><![CDATA[bbbb]]></phrase>
<phrase name="3333"><![CDATA[cccc]]></phrase>
...
```

and

```
xml 2

<phrase name="1111"><![CDATA[dddd]]></phrase>
<phrase name="2222"><![CDATA[eeee]]></phrase>
<phrase name="4444"><![CDATA[ffff]]></phrase>
...
```

Now the text in elements with the same name should be overwriten with the text from xml 2

```
output

<phrase name="1111"><![CDATA[dddd]]></phrase>
<phrase name="2222"><![CDATA[eeee]]></phrase>  
<phrase name="3333"><![CDATA[cccc]]></phrase>
...
```

Any ideas on how to do this as easy as possible?
I already tried using XSLT, but im new to it and it didnt work, the way i need it.
Is doesn't need to be done with XSLT, if there is any programm that can handle this.

thanks for your help

Comment: I think you need to gives us more information on what you want to do.  What language are you using?  We can start from there. In theory you can basically copy and paste the values. lol

Comment: @ArnaldoCapo The language he is using is XSLT. When it comes to using that the important questions are what processor is being used and what version of XSLT. So, OP, along with that bit of information can you also update your question to show us what XSLT you have tried? There are a lot of questions on here about merging XML if you are looking for a place to start.

Comment: I looked through most of the questions but didn't find what i was looking for. I can't just copy and paste through 2000 lines of xml. I dont need to use xslt if there is any better solution for merging 2 xml files.

Comment: @MatthewGreen - That's exactly what I meant. Thanks for clearing that out. :)

Comment: Well can you at least update your question with something that you have tried? You typically won't get someone to answer the question without you showing that you've tried something yourself. Plus the answers are better if we know where you are coming from in your code.

Comment: @MatthewGreen thanks for the tips. I tried the whole day and now im stuck with no solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output cdata-section-elements="phrase" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//phrase">
        <xsl:variable name="name"><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy><xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="document('second.xml')//phrase[@name=$name]">
               <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
               <xsl:value-of select="document('second.xml')//phrase[@name=$name]" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

when applied to an input file `first.xml` the form of

```
<doc>
<phrase name="1111"><![CDATA[aaaa]]></phrase>
<phrase name="2222"><![CDATA[bbbb]]></phrase>
<phrase name="3333"><![CDATA[cccc]]></phrase>       
</doc>
```

where a second input file `second.xml` the form of

```
<doc>
<phrase name="1111"><![CDATA[dddd]]></phrase>
<phrase name="2222"><![CDATA[eeee]]></phrase>
<phrase name="4444"><![CDATA[ffff]]></phrase>
</doc>
```

is present produces the wanted result of

```
<doc>
<phrase name="1111"><![CDATA[dddd]]></phrase>
<phrase name="2222"><![CDATA[eeee]]></phrase>
<phrase name="3333"><![CDATA[cccc]]></phrase>       
</doc>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have one question: is it possible to save the output in a new file?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. How this is done depends on the XSLT processing tool.

Comment: What would be the best to use here? i tried the code using firefox to run the xsl file...

Comment: And i have another problem, the text i wanted to change was inside <![CDATA[myText]]> and after i used the xsl the CDATA is deleted and it only says myText

Comment: Using Firefox it should be possible to just "File" > "Save Page As". Which processor to choose depends on the use case and personal preference. You can find some options here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT_processor#Processor_implementations
For the second part I think it was good if you added some detail to your sample code either by editing your question or asking a separate one because the original problem of this question seems to be solved.

Comment: You really helped me a lot! I edited the question, because i think a new question would be redundant.